# How can I make a lightning-input-field (LWC) not required?

Tags: salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am using a lightning-record-edit-form as shown below

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Client_Intake__c">
    <lightning-input-field  name="Id" field-name="Hub_Spoke_Account__c" style="width: 650px;" onchange={handleAccountFieldChange}></lightning-input-field>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

According to https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/form-element/ , the lightning-input-field control value is supposed to be required only if we add the required attribute to it. Even though I  do not have the required attribute set on the lightning-input-field , it is still being displayed as a required field.
How can I fix this? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late to the party here, but:

Even though you haven't specified the field as required on the lightning-input-field, the field is still required in Setup, hence why it is showing as required here. This is a feature (or limitation if you will) of the lightning-record-edit form. The only solution really is to set the field as not required in Setup -> Object Manager, and to only make it required on the relevant page layouts where applicable.

Also, you will get answers a lot faster on salesforce.stackexchange.com